# change UITableView setBackgroundColor if UISearchBar is populated

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

If anyone could help me with this, that would be great. Thanks in advance Max

I want to change UITableView setBackgroundColor from clearColor to whiteColor if text is entered in UISearchBar .

i.e. the placeholder text disappears.

Immediately when text is deleted i.e. placeholder text reappears

the UITableView setBackgroundColor resumes to clearColor.

```
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 140, 320, 170);

    UISearchBar *searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 100, 300, 40)];
    [searchBar setDelegate:self];
    [searchBar setPlaceholder:@"Species/Common Name"];
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES];
    [searchBar setTintColor:kITBarTint];
    [self.view addSubview:searchBar];

    self.tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:frame style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    [self.view addSubview:self.tableView];
    [self.tableView setTableHeaderView:header];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think You should do your changes in UISearchBarDelegate's method - (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar

Comment: Would you be able to elaborate a little more, I need a bit more help as haven't been programming Objective C for long. Would I apply an if statement in this instance?

Answer (score 2):

Use the search bar delegate:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[UISearchBarDelegate Protocol Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Use one of the delegate's methods:

```
- (void)searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
```

UISearchBar has property [text](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISearchBar_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UISearchBar) so you can check for user input.

For example:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    if([searchText length] > 0) 
    {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    }
    else
    {
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change colors in delegate function of search bar like
- (void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar

- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)theSearchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText

and put the     self.tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yourcolor];